# Deleting user profiles based off of date last modified, via powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am working on a project for my employer- the goal is to take a subset of our machines, which are rather constantly filling up due to an excess of profiles, many from people who are no longer employees. On doing research into this, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72101998/22953610 by John Smith, which seems immensely helpful and exactly what we want to do.

I am , however, running into one issue: When executing the script, it prints as expected, but does not as far as I can tell actually take any action. I will post the Powershell script below.

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$ExcludedUsers="Public","default","defaultuser0","public","administrator"
$path = "$Env:SystemDrive\users"

## getting the name of the users
## this returns the filtered results below
$useraccounts = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude $ExcludedUsers | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}

## $useraccounts returns

<#

Directory: /Users

UnixMode   User             Group                 LastWriteTime           Size Name
--------   ----             -----                 -------------           ---- ----
drwxr-x--- jacoby         staff                5/2/2022 19:04           1056 jacoby
drwxrwxrwt root             wheel               3/26/2022 00:21            128 Shared

#>

## $useraccounts.name returns

<#

PS > $useraccounts.name

jacoby
Shared

#>

## if we use get-childitem | get-member we can see that we have access to a lot of
## properties returned like the .name value

#### we don't need any of this
####$sort = $useraccounts | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
#####$removeaccounts = $sort -join '|'

## ok let's do something here
## for each account in my list
foreach ($account in $useraccounts)
{

    ## let's write some info so we know what's happening
    Write-Verbose -Message ('currently working with {0}' -f $account)

    ## we want to check moditfication time of folder so we gotta see if it exists
    ## we want to test c:\users\ the current account \ appdata\local
    ## $account.FullName gives us c:\users\accountname so we just need to add the rest

    $testpath1 = $account.FullName + '\appdata\local'
    Write-Verbose -Message ('we generated the path {0}' -f $testpath1)

    ## imma give you some error checking
    ## this is ugly because it could be there but we can't access it

    if ((Test-Path -Path $testpath1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $true)
    {

        ## if the path exists here's what we'll do

        ## get a count of all the file modified in the last 30 days

        $count = (Get-ChildItem -Path $testpath1 | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }).Count

        ## now that we have a count we can test if the count is less than than 1 (0)
        ## that means no files in these folders were modified in the last 30 days

        if ($count -lt 1) {

            ####
            ##
            ## this is the area where we can take action on the
            ## folders/files that have not been modified in the
            ## last 30 days
            ## you might delete them or just log them somewbere
            ##
            ####

            Write-Verbose -Message 'no file modified in the last 30 days'

            ####
            ## this is your original deletion pipeline
            Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_userprofile | Where-Object {($_.LocalPath -contains "$account") -and (!$_.special)} | Remove-WmiObject
            ##i have not tested this. be careful.
            ####
        }

        else {

            Write-Verbose -Message ('{0} files have been modified in the last 30 days! We do not want delete this.' -f $count)

            ####
            ##
            ## these is the area where we can take action if the
            ## files/folder HAVE been modified recently
            ## we would NOT want to delete these files
            ##
            ####
        }
    }
    ## do some stuff before ending the for each loop
    ## maybe write our changes somewhere permanent
}
```

My goal here is to actually go through and fully delete all user profiles not modified in the last 30 days.

I see the deletion pipeline is as follows:

```
            ####
            ## this is your original deletion pipeline
            Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_userprofile | Where-Object {($_.LocalPath -contains "$account") -and (!$_.special)} | Remove-WmiObject
            ##i have not tested this. be careful.
            ####
```

I have removed the hashtags so as to uncomment it. When running the script, however, I get only the following result:

```
VERBOSE: currently working with C:\Users\#088DFEBE.jpg
VERBOSE: we generated the path C:\Users\#088DFEBE.jpg\appdata\local
VERBOSE: currently working with C:\Users\#76B7EBF1.doc
VERBOSE: we generated the path C:\Users\#76B7EBF1.doc\appdata\local
VERBOSE: currently working with C:\Users\#8A09F1A9.xls
VERBOSE: we generated the path C:\Users\#8A09F1A9.xls\appdata\local
VERBOSE: currently working with C:\Users\#D97B2BA6.pptx
VERBOSE: we generated the path C:\Users\#D97B2BA6.pptx\appdata\local
VERBOSE: currently working with C:\Users\$42D864D7.doc
VERBOSE: we generated the path C:\Users\$42D864D7.doc\appdata\local
VERBOSE: currently working with C:\Users\$649D0AFD.pptx
VERBOSE: we generated the path C:\Users\$649D0AFD.pptx\appdata\local
VERBOSE: currently working with C:\Users\$D4DC362C.xls
VERBOSE: we generated the path C:\Users\$D4DC362C.xls\appdata\local
VERBOSE: currently working with C:\Users\$EA0D76A7.jpg
VERBOSE: we generated the path C:\Users\$EA0D76A7.jpg\appdata\local
```

And that is all it does.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong, that it is not actually going through and deleting profiles?

Comment: Your code looks a little unnecessarily complex ... this may help: [Delete User Profiles with PowerShell & CIM](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-delete-user-profile/)

Comment: There's also a group policy that does this, but it depends on reboots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It looks like your first `Get-ChildItem` call also matches *files*, which you can prevent via the `-Directory` switch.
- `AppData` is a *hidden* directory, so you need `-Force` with `Get-ChildItem` in order to enumerate it.
- As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

However, I suggest the following, streamlined approach:

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile | 
  Where-Object -OutVariable profilesToDelete { 
    -not $_.Special -and 
      (Split-Path -Parent $_.LocalPath) -eq "$env:SystemDrive\Users" -and
      (Split-Path -Leaf $_.LocalPath) -notin 'Public', 'default', 'defaultuser0', 'administrator' -and
      $_.LastUseTime -lt (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-30)
  } |
  Remove-CimInstance -WhatIf

# To also delete the user accounts associated with the deleted profiles:
Remove-LocalUser -SID $profilesToDelete.SID -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the commands above ***previews* the operations**. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure a given operation will do what you want.</sup>

- The above uses the [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) and [`Remove-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/remove-ciminstance)  CIM cmdlets.
- Whether a given user profile was *used* (logged onto) in the last 30 days is inferred from the `.LastUseTime` property of each [`Win32_UserProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ee886409(v=vs.85)) instance returned .

  - Note: You seemingly *must* run *with elevation* (as administrator) to be able to merely *query* this value.
- In addition to removing the *profile* (directory and registry entries), you may also want to delete the associated *user accounts*, which is what the [`Remove-LocalUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/remove-localuser) call does.

  - Note the use of the [common `-OutVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable) on the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call with self-chosen variable name `profilesToDelete` (note: *without* the `$` at that point), allowing later access to the profiles targeted for deletion via `$profilesToDelete`.